# missing wi-fi adapter on my acer notebook

Tags: acer, connection, adapter

i seemed to have been virus bombed earlier this year, and my keyboard is still not functioning fully but with an external keyboard solved that, however, now I recently started using the acer again, locally, I can "see" the local provided of internet, BUT I cannot connect,
having tried a few things I got a notice that stated "wifi adapter missing"  please can anyone reliable explain how I can re-install that , or .advise me .other procedures that solves my connection problems. Please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: i feel that even attempted correction gets blocked, terminal wont read my p/word, so can anyone tell me how I can clear /CLEAN my ubuntu files ..as this may be the core pof the problem..

Comment: Sounds like you should maybe do a fresh install...